# Can't Install IE 10 on brand new Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-update, internet-explorer-10

I bought a new Alienware and they won't provide support for Windows Update (why should they, really).  I go and try to run the IE 10 update like so:

[image]

And, it hangs a bit on the screen above.  Then, it shows this error:

[image]

How can I install IE 10?  I already tried installing it directly, but that doesn't work either?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

Latest error log after installing System Update Readiness Tool:

```
00:00.000: ====================================================================
00:00.484: Started: 2013/05/12 (Y/M/D) 19:31:22.265 (local)
00:00.515: Time Format in this log: MM:ss.mmm (minutes:seconds.milliseconds)
00:00.562: Command line: "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install\WU-IE10-Windows7-x64.exe" /WU-SILENT
00:00.624: INFO:    Setup installer for Internet Explorer: 10.0.9200.16521
00:00.656: INFO:    Previous version of Internet Explorer: 9.0.8112.16476
00:00.671: INFO:    Checking if iexplore.exe's current version is between 10.0.8100.0...
00:00.687: INFO:    ...and 10.1.0.0...
00:00.702: INFO:    Maximum version on which to run IEAK branding is: 10.1.0.0...
00:00.734: INFO:    iexplore.exe version check success. Install can proceed.
00:00.749: INFO:    Operating System: Windows Workstation: 6.1.7601 (Service Pack 1)
00:00.780: INFO:    Trying to extract ID: SetupDownloadList.txt (0) as "SetupDownloadList.txt"
00:00.796: INFO:    Trying to extract ID: HardwareBlockingList.xml (0) as "HardwareBlockingList.xml"
00:00.858: INFO:    Trying to extract ID: 7006 (0) as "IE10-neutral.Extracted.cab"
00:01.155: INFO:    Trying to extract ID: 5501 (1033) as "Spelling_en.msu"
00:01.373: INFO:    Extracted Spelling dictionary for en to C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp\Spelling_en.msu.
00:01.467: INFO:    Trying to extract ID: 5502 (1033) as "Hyphenation_en.msu"
00:01.498: INFO:    Extracted Hyphenation dictionary for en to C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp\Hyphenation_en.msu.
00:01.529: INFO:    Trying to extract ID: 7128 (1033) as "IE10-support.cab"
00:15.788: INFO:    Updated Download list, Hardware Blocking list, and no reboot policy files successfully downloaded and extracted for use.
00:15.835: INFO:    Launched program to check hardware: "C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp\IE10-SUPPORT\IEXPLORE.EXE" /CheckHardware "C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp\IE10-support\HardwareBlockingList.xml"
00:16.318: INFO:    Hardware support check succeeded. Installation will continue.
00:16.349: INFO:    Windows 7 operating system detected.
00:16.396: INFO:    Service pack major: 1
00:16.443: INFO:    Service pack minor: 0
00:16.474: INFO:    Service pack name:  Service Pack 1
00:16.739: INFO:    Version Check for (KB2670838) of C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll: 6.2.9200.16492 >= 6.2.9200.16492 (True)
00:16.771: INFO:    Version Check for (KB2639308) of C:\Windows\System32\Ntoskrnl.exe: 6.1.7601.18113 >= 6.1.7601.17727 (True)
00:16.895: INFO:    Version Check for (KB2533623) of C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-security-base-l1-1-0.dll: 6.1.7601.18015 >= 6.1.7601.17617 (True)
00:16.927: INFO:    Version Check for (KB2731771) of C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll: 6.1.7601.18015 >= 6.1.7601.17932 (True)
00:16.958: INFO:    Checking for correct version of C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui.ttf.
00:17.051: INFO:    Version Check for (KB2786081) of C:\Windows\System32\taskhost.exe: 6.1.7601.18010 >= 6.1.7601.18010 (True)
00:27.129: INFO:    IE Setup Language pack included: C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp\IE-Spelling-en.cab
00:27.644: INFO:    IE Setup Language pack included: C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp\IE-Hyphenation-en.cab
00:27.737: INFO:    Waiting for 0 prerequisite downloads.
00:29.235: INFO:    The neutral pack was successfully downloaded from the internet. Installation will continue using the downloaded package.
00:29.344: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiStart(0), lParam=0x001e2b60 returned 0x00000000.
00:29.797: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiScan(1), lParam=0x00000001 returned 0x00000000.
00:29.906: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiStartInstall(4), lParam=0x00000001 returned 0x00000014.
00:29.968: INFO:    Installing with the downloaded package. C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp\IE10-neutral.Downloaded.cab
00:30.015: INFO:    Launched package installation: C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp\IE10-neutral.Downloaded.cab /quiet /norestart
01:30.824: INFO:    Process exit code 0x80092004 (-2146885628) [Cannot find object or property. ]
01:31.011: ERROR:   Neutral package installation failed (exit code = 0x80092004 (2148081668)).
01:31.058: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiInstallDone(7), lParam=0x00009c59 returned 0x00000000.
01:31.089: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiStartFinish(11), lParam=0x00000000 returned 0x00000000.
01:31.214: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiFinish(12), lParam=0x00000000 returned 0x00000016.
01:31.261: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete.
01:31.370: ERROR:   Couldn't create setup troubleshooting shortcut on the desktop. HRESULT: 0x80070002,
01:31.401: INFO:    Setup exit code: 0x00009C59 (40025) - The neutral cab failed to install.
01:32.291: INFO:    Scheduling upload to IE SQM server: http://sqm.microsoft.com/sqm/ie/sqmserver.dll
01:40.449: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup0.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:40.590: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup1.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:40.637: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup2.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:40.793: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup3.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:41.011: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup4.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:41.058: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup5.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:41.183: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup6.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:41.229: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup7.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:41.292: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup8.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:41.354: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup9.sqm" with error: 2147500036
01:41.401: INFO:    Cleaning up temporary files in: C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp
01:41.588: INFO:    Unable to remove directory C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1AC83.tmp, marking for deletion on reboot.
01:41.729: INFO:    Released Internet Explorer Installer Mutex
```

**Edit:**

C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CheckSUR.log:

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7601.21645
Package Version 18.0
2013-05-12 19:22

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x00000000  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum       Expected file name Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~neutral~~10.2.9200.16437.mum does not match the actual file name
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x00000000  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum      Expected file name Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~neutral~~10.2.9200.16437.mum does not match the actual file name

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages

Checking Component Store

Summary:
Seconds executed: 199
 Found 2 errors
  CBS MUM Corrupt Total count: 2

Unavailable repair files:
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.cat
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.cat

Customer Experience report successfully uploaded.  Thank you for participating.  For more information, see the Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program on the Microsoft web site.
```

**Edit:**

Latest C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CheckSUR.log:

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7601.21645
Package Version 18.0
2013-05-15 19:17

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x00000000  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum       Expected file name Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~neutral~~10.2.9200.16437.mum does not match the actual file name
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x00000000  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum      Expected file name Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~neutral~~10.2.9200.16437.mum does not match the actual file name

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages

Checking Component Store

Summary:
Seconds executed: 433
 Found 2 errors
  CBS MUM Corrupt Total count: 2

Unavailable repair files:
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.cat
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.cat

Customer Experience report successfully uploaded.  Thank you for participating.  For more information, see the Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program on the Microsoft web site.
```

Comment: look for a file called IE10_main.log, open it and look for error messages. If you're unsure, upload the file.

Comment: @Ramhound Good news, no integrity violations.  Microsoft has free support?  Where can I find that?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I found the log file in C:\Windows and it has a warning `00:02.496: WARNING: Checking version for C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll.  The file does not exist.` and an error `02:33.443: ERROR:   SQM Upload failed while uploading "C:\Users\Dom\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup0.sqm" with error: 2147500036`

Comment: @magicandre1981 There is another error as well `01:50.480: ERROR:   Neutral package installation failed (exit code = 0x80092004 (2148081668)).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that finally worked for me:  Install IE 11!  Haha take that IE 10!

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same error. 6 hours later I'm finally able to install IE 10. It turns out there are some corrupt downloaded packages and IE 10 cannot install. pkgmgr.exe is a utility to manage these packages.

This is what you need to do. (not documented anywhere of course) Run a **DOS COMMAND** window (CMD) **as admin** and type the following commands:

`pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437`

`pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437`

And you're going to run this on any version you find lower than the one you're trying to install (from what I see "**10.2.9200.16437**") and that you find here **C:\Windows\servicing\Packages**. These are the files that are mainly causing the issue. For example:

`pkgmgr /UP:pkgmgr /up:Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~8.0.7601.17514`

You would replace **8.0.7601.17514** with whatever file names you find on the **packages** folder I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly, I am not sure I understand "run this on any version you find lower than the one you're trying to install."  Can't I just uninstall everything related to IE 10 and reinstall?  Or, can I reinstall Windows 7 or upgrade to Windows 8 and would that fix it?  Just looking for the easiest way out of this... :)

Comment: Honestly, the easiest thing is to format the C: drive and just re-install Windows. Depending on the amount of software, settings, files and data that you have, it may not be the fastest way, however.

I meant, look for files with this name "Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~" in the folder in bold and run the pkgmgr command on those files. You need to remove any InternetExplorer packages older than the one you're trying to install.

I'm still perplexed at why Microsoft did not include this in their installation logic. It's their own OS!!!

Comment: I am amazed that it's this hard to install IE 10, too!  I just wish I understood what you meant so I could do it...  I don't want to have to reinstall my OS and lose all my stuff.  How many files would I have to run the command on?  Just the two that you mentioned?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: In addition to running it on those two files, just go to c:\windows\Servicing\Packages, list files (command DIR) with this pattern: Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~* and run the pkgmgr command on the files that you find that are less than version 10. The version is where you see the * on the file. What's happened is that Windows Update tried to install/update IE 8, 9 or 10 and got stuck and corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, Jose.  I think I understand well enough to give it a shot now.

Comment: Using the script from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2579295: FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*10.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart" to clear every package of IE10, finally IE10 is installed.  Thanks to Jose.

Answer (score 3):

I followed Jose Ortiz's instructions and successfully got rid of IE10 upgrade failure code 9c59, however, one correction to Jose's instructions, not only I had to pkgmgr /UP: on the lower versions of Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~* in C:\Windows\servicing\Packages but also higher version 10 ones as well. then the IE10 upgrade becomes successful

also one side effect to share, once I uninstalled the the lower versions of Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~, I was asked to restart the system, after that my IE9 dropped down to IE8. then I decided to remove the higher versions of Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~ as well, try IE10 installation one more time then it's successful

Comment: Thanks for posting.  The instructions were too difficult for me to follow...  I don't want to have to go through each file and do all that.  I am disappointed Microsoft hasn't fixed this yet.

Comment: Great, this fixed my issue (IE11 failing with  Neutral package installation failed (exit code = 0x80092004). I only had to /UP (uninstall) the IE11 package file. Brand new Win7 install, but trying to install IE11 over the original IE8 had failed. I then installed IE9 and IE10 no problem, but IE11 still failed. The /UP fixed it.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

After reading @jose-ortiz's very helpful answers and the comments, I did the following when I could not upgrade from IE 10 to 11 on a Windows 7 x64 machine I was working on. I think these steps may also help someone else, regardless of whether they are trying to update to IE10 or IE11 so I'm posting them:

1. Run the following:

   FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*8.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"

   FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*9.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"

   FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*10.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"

   FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*11.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"

   FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-IE*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"
2. Reboot
3. Install all required IE 11 prerequisites updates from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2847882/prerequisite-updates-for-internet-explorer-11
4. Reboot
5. Run the Windows CheckSUR program. Download and install from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness-tool
6. Install IE11 using the offline installer. Google "IE 11 Offline Installer" for that download.
7. Reboot and you should have the latest version of IE

Comment: Thank you for your scripts for uninstalling the IE packages. Without them I would have never managed to install IE11 on Windows 7 .

Answer (score 1):

0x80092004 = CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND.

```
//
// MessageId: CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND
//
// MessageText:
//
// Cannot find object or property.
//
#define CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND                _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80092004L)
```

To fix this, run the System Update Readiness Tool (KB947821):

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821/en-us

Reboot and try again to install the IE10.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that didn't work.  I get a even more errors now; I updated the question with the latest error log entry.

Comment: also upload the checkSur.log from the CBS folder.

Comment: I have added the checkSur.log file.  Thank you.

Comment: ok, you already have some IE10 files on the HDD. If you have a second PC with Ie10 and Win7, copy the 2 damaged files into the servicing folder. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619779%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I copied the files and verified that they were in there; then I ran the System Update Readiness tool, but it appears it's still saying they're corrupt.  I updated the question with the updated checkSur.log file.

Comment: do you see some IE10 updates in Control panel->Program & Features? Try to remove them. You can also try to expand the IE10 installer (/x switch) copy the MSU files to \Windows\CheckSUR\packages and checksur again: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2010/05/26/using-checksur-and-update-packages-to-fix-corruption.aspx

Comment: No there is no IE10 in Control Panel (or IE 9 for that matter).  Would reinstalling Windows fix this?  Would I lose all my data?  What about upgrading to Windows 8 (which I don't want to do!)?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: try the second part of my last comment. Extract the MSU fiel from the IE10 setup with the /X switch, copy them to the path I mentioned and run checksur again.

Comment: Thanks, I would've tried that but I was confused.  What .MSU am I looking to copy?  The unrepairable files in my CheckSUR.log are .MUM and .CAT files.  Also, what is `/x switch`.  I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Run **IE10-Windows6.1-x64-en-US.exe /X:D:\IE10** to extract the IE10. Now copy the MSU files to C:\Windows\CheckSUR\packages and run checksur update again. Now loo inside the checksur.log if all files are now repaired.

Answer (score 1):

I spent over a day trying to resolve the Code 9C59 error I kept getting while trying to upgrade IE 9 to 10 on a Windows 7 system. Jose Ortiz's posting finally allowed me to fix the problem with the `pkgmgr` command. For the laptop on which I encountered the problem, the following commands fixed the problem allowing me to successfully complete the upgrade:

```
pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437

pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437

pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~10.2.9200.16521

pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~9.4.8112.16421
```

I tried many other suggestions I found elsewhere before finally being able to fix the problem with the solution I found here. I've [posted all the error messages](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/ie/9c59/) I found in log files, such as the `CheckSUR.log` and Windows System event log for those who may also have found issues reported with spelling and hyphenation files in the `CheckSUR.log` file after running the System Update Readiness Tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  I was running IE8 (fresh install), tried to update and it failed.  I tried updating to IE 9 (sucessfully).  Then attempted to update to IE11 same error.

Looking in c:\Windows\IE11_main.log log file I found this ...
Setup exit code: 0x00009C59 (40025) - The neutral cab failed to install.

Running each of the prerequisites for IE11 individually worked for me there are 6 of them and it took me about 10 minutes .....
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2847882

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question which is about installing IE 10, not IE 11